Flags of Vector Spaces: Book/Note Recommendations
I am looking for resources (i.e. lecture notes, books) on flags/towers of vector spaces, besides the basic results about refining, completeness, or whether $T \in \operatorname{Hom}(V)$ is upper triangularizable.
For reference, I am referring to the  following definition:
Definition (Flag). Let $V$ be a vector space with $\dim V = n$. A flag $\mathfrak{F}$ of length $k$ in $V$ is a collection of subspaces $$ \{0\} = V_0 \subset V_1 \subset \cdots \subset V_k = V,$$ where $V_i \neq V_{i +1}$ for all $i \in \{0,1,\dots, k-1\}$.
I would also be interested in references on flag varieties, but those are a bit easier to find online.

There are not enough results on flags of vector spaces to fill a book. In books on Lie algebras flags of vector spaces are discussed in order to prove Lie's theorem. Did you see the references at wikipedia?

@DietrichBurde I did check out the wikipedia references, though there's not many. Thanks for the note on Lie algebras, that's pretty neat. Even if there are not many results about flags, I'm surprised no one has compiled a formulation of introductory linear algebra in terms of flags. Whether or not it would be pedagogically useful, I think it would be a neat project, since many theorems written in terms of bases could be rewritten via statements about flags.
